# Why duplicate file descriptors rather than move them when swapping stdout with stderr in bash?

Tags: bash, file-descriptor, io-redirection

I've seen this idiom around:

```
cmd 3>&1 1>&2 2>&3 3>&-
```

but my question is, why not just move them?

```
cmd 3>&1- 1>&2- 2>&3-
```

Is there a reason for this?

Comment: I have 12 different shells installed on my computer and only 2 of them (bash and ksh) support that syntax. Why make your script less portable for mere fluff?

Comment: That's a answer @oguzismail.  Shouldn't be in the comment section.

Comment: It's interesting @oguzismail, I tried to lookup other shells like csh, tcsh, zsh and I couldn't find equivalent syntax in their man pages.  If the first set does work on these shells, then maybe the second set does also?

Comment: Shells I tested (without changing the command in your question) are bash-3.2.57 (this is /bin/sh on macos), bash, bosh, dash, gwsh, ksh, mksh, mrsh, oksh, pdksh, posh, and yash. I believe it'll work on zsh too and not on busybox sh, netbsd/freebsd sh, and ksh88; but haven't tested.

Comment: Are you saying @oguzismail, that you've tested the first or second variation above on those shells?

Comment: Both. The first variation works everywhere, it's POSIX. The second is bash/ksh only.